# Case remove null values in each column

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am trying to remove null values from my query.

| Val_1 | Val_2 | Condition_1 | Condition_2 | Condition_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | NULL | NULL | 0.508850000 |
| X | Y | 0.116350000 | NULL | NULL |
| X | Y | 0.000000000 | NULL | NULL |
| X | Y | 0.000000000 | NULL | NULL |
| X | Y | NULL | 0.000000000 | NULL |
| X | Y | NULL | 0.046050000 | NULL |
| X | Y | NULL | NULL | 7.385500000 |

X and Y are identical strings. I am trying to create this, removing null values and keeping all the non-null values together:

| Var_1 | Var_2 | Condition_1 | Condition_2 | Condition_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | 0.116350000 | 0.000000000 | 0.508850000 |
| X | Y | 0.000000000 | 0.046050000 | 7.385500000 |
| X | Y | 0.000000000 | NULL | NULL |

Currently, I have this

```
Select Table_1.Var_1,
      Table_1.Var_2,
      Avg(CASE WHEN Table_2.Conditions = 'Condition_1' Then Table_1.Values END) As Condition_1,
      Avg(CASE WHEN Table_2.Conditions = 'Condition_2' Then Table_1.Values END) As Condition_2,
      Avg(CASE WHEN Table_2.Conditions = 'Condition_3' Then Table_1.Values END) As Condition_3,
From Table_1
        INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
Group BY Table_1.Val_1, Table_2.Val_2, Table_1.ID
Order By Table_1.Val_1, Table_2.Val_2
```

Table 1 holds the values, Table 2 holds the conditions. These are joined via a common ID number. Each value can have only one of the three conditions.  Aggregate functions such as max just returns a single value, but I need all the values that are not null. I was thinking of wrapping this query in a subquery and then modifying it accordingly, but I'm really unsure if that will work.

Table 1 Sample

| ID | Another value | Val_1 | Val_2 | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 15 | X | Y | 0.29000 |
| 01 | 15 | X | Y | 1.20000 |
| 01 | 15 | X | Y | 3.38000 |

Table 2 Sample

| ID | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 |
| 01 | 2 |
| 01 | 3 |

Comment: Could you provide some sample from `Table_1` and `Table_2 `?

Comment: Probably with just `IFNULL(Avg(CASE ....),0)`?

Comment: Had another post that IFNULL() did not actually work, may have been a bug in earlier version.  Doing COALESCE( Avg(), 0 ) is probably better option.

Comment: I have tried both of those instances and it just replaces my null values with 0. @D-Shih I have edited the original post with samples, there are more values in both tables, however they are irrelevant to the query

Comment: There is no way to easily "bubble up" non-null values.  Did that table come from somewhere else?  Maybe we can bypass this mess.